# Is there any way to prevent Trello email attachments?

Tags: email, attachment, trello

Trello has a great feature where you can reply to card comments via email. Many of our non-Trello savvy clients enjoy this feature.

But this week, a client that has seven different little icons and logos included in their email signature has used the reply-to-card feature, and now our cards are getting loaded with these attachments.

Is there a way to turn off attachments via email in Trello?